# Flutter - Warning (CocoaPods not installed Skipping pod install) Even While Installed

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods, podfile

I am trying to build a Flutter app with Geolocator plugin on Android Studio.
When I am running the app I have the following warning - that prevents the app from running:

> Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
> CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
> Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
> For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
> To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
>
> Exception: CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.

I tried every solution i found in the internet (Stackoverflow & GitHub) but nothing seems to work.

Important: When I tried to run the app from Xcode instead of from Android Studio, I had this error:

> The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

So what I did was - Change directory to ios (on the Flutter project) and running:

```
pod init
pod install
```

Tried to run again from Xcode and it worked perfectly.
After it works on Xcode I tried to run it from Android Studio and the same error happens to me, preventing the app to launch.

Flutter Doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-IL)
    • Flutter version 2.2.2 at /Users/idanrefaeli/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision d79295af24 (5 weeks ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
    • Dart version 2.13.3

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/idanrefaeli/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Idan’s (mobile) • 00008020-0011092101A2002E • ios            • iOS 14.6
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Extra logs:
'Run' log in Android Studio: pastebin.com/7iYtdcTQ
Also this terminal log after running 'pod install': pastebin.com/1cCNuFYM

-- UPDATE --

I finally was able to run the app, all I did was to copy all the project files to a new project from scratch and it worked.
Maybe some conflict caused this issue, it was my last resort of course.

Comment: I had the same problem using VS Code, but it was resolved when I reopened it.

Comment: I tried reopening, restarting, flutter clean, everything

Comment: Show us the complete error (print) please. I'm trying to reproduce it.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/7iYtdcTQ
Also this terminal log after running 'pod install': https://pastebin.com/1cCNuFYM

Comment: The same problem((

Answer (score 29):

In the app Terminal after open Simulator write

```
flutter run
```

in the Terminal

or
close Android Studio and open terminal and paste

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

it will open the Android Studio and you can run as normal

Comment: this: `open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app` worked for me

Comment: This one really helps, no need to install the patch 1 for Android Studio Bumblebee, just run open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app

Comment: Quit the android studio and execute open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app in terminal. started working !

Comment: open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app works like charm, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

```
# uninstall
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
brew uninstall cocoapods

# reinstall
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup

# rebuild
flutter build ios
```

Then, *restart vscode and iTerm* (it is important), and debug

Comment: Finally fixed my issue using these commands +1

Comment: most complete and simple answer. +1

Answer (score 11):

This error started appearing in mac os after the update

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744, built on January 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.0.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.bloc.intellij_generator_plugin (3.3.0), Dart (211.7798), andrasferenczi.dart-data-plugin (0.2.0), com.thoughtworks.gauge (211.6693.111), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40), io.flutter (63.2.2), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)
```

In my case, it is working to launch project in vs code, or running project with command `flutter run`

**Android Canary last version solved problem**

**Update**:
As Ascot Harris mentioned, Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1 solves problem

Comment: Android Canary is a good solution for now, thanks

Comment: Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1 solved the issue for me

Answer (score 5):

**STEP 1:**
close Android Studio

**STEP 2:**
open *terminal*

**STEP 3:**
paste:

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

**STEP 4:**
*Android Studio* will be opened auto.

**STEP 5:**
click run **▶** button

Answer (score 4):

just open terminal and write

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

this solve problem in my case

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I installed cocoapods and it works now.

Just copy and paste this line to install cocoapods:
`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Restart VSCode and terminals.

And then run your app.

I'm working on MAC with IOS (Iphone 13) emulator.

[CocoaPods Guide.](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 3):

first of all you should do this command below:

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6
```

then:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible hack, which sometimes works.

I run the app from Visual Studio code once and the subsequent run in Android Studio work

Answer (score 0):

As @islomkhuja-akhrarov mentioned it's an Android Studio Bumblebee problem, installing patch 1 helped

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by deleting

`Podfile.lock` pods folder

updating these packages

```
firebase_core: ^1.12.0
firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.3.0.
firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0.
```

then running first

pod repo remove trunk

and finally

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

for me closing and reopening the VS code fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It can also be the case if your updating the xcode so wait till the installation complete